# Necessary changes required to use import {general_js} from 'general-js-toolkit' instead of import {checkIsEmpty} from 'general-js-toolkit/dist/util'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How can I modify my published npm package to allow users to import my package using the syntax import { general_js } from 'general-js-toolkit', instead of the current syntax import { checkIsEmpty } from 'general-js-toolkit/dist/util'? What changes do I need to make to my package to achieve this?

this is my repo url :

```
https://github.com/vitabletech/general-js-toolkit
```

this is How I want to use
Usage
To use general-js-toolkit in my project, simply include it in our HTML or import it in our JavaScript file:

```
<script src="path/to/general-js-toolkit.js"></script>
```

```
import general-js-toolkit from 'general-js-toolkit';
```

Once I have included general-js-toolkit, I can use its functions by calling them directly:

```
const result = general-js-toolkit.someFunction(args);
```

can someone help me ?

I have tried multiple ways to import the required functions in js file but it always gives an error **Object(...) is not a function**. any other way of importing could help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen you code on github, My suggestion is Instead of using of babel `"build": "babel src -d dist"` you can use **webpack**.

you can follow below step in your project

- `npm install webpack webpack-cli --save-dev`
- Create a new file called **webpack.config.js** in the root directory of your package, with the following contents:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'general-js-toolkit.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: 'generalJs',//give the better name if you do not like but if it is set once then we will not change it in the future.
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  }
};
```

- replace **"main": "dist/index.js"**, to this **"main": "dist/general-js-toolkit.js"** in **package.json** file
- also add this in **package.json** file `"module": "src/index.js"`
- replace  "build": "babel src -d dist" with this `npx webpack --config webpack.config.js`
- To check package in local before publish run `npm pack` cmd
- after you got the package file copy it into your any project like your react project
- run cmd `npm install <path/of/pack/file>`
- `import { function_name } from 'general-js-toolkit';`
- `console.log(function_name(''));`

#### How General users like HTML or PHP developer use our package

```
<body>
<script src="dist/general-js-toolkit.js"></script>
    <script>
        console.log(generalJs.function_name(''));
      </script>
</body>
```

#### How react  developer  can use it

```
import { function_name } from 'general-js-toolkit';
console.log(function_name(''));
```